# What if local storage is not enough

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, local-storage, session-storage

I have some test project going on in angularjs. Where i store the user into the local storage once the application is loaded. The user contains a array list of items. but now i want to a array list of tasklist which also contains a array of items.

So the structure would be something like this not sure if the json is completely correct but its to illustrate the question:

```
{
    "user": {
        "items": [
            {"name":"Beer"},
            {"name":"Wine"}
            ....
        ],
        "taskitems": [
            {"name":"taskitems1",
               "items": [
            {"name":"Beer"},
            {"name":"Wine"}
            ....
        ],

    }
}
```

Now let's say that the user has 20 properties and there are 2000 items inside the item array. And i have 1000 task items which all have 2000 items. and the list keeps growing until the local storage is too small. What would be a better approach to make sure i don't overuse the local storage.

**EDIT**
This is how i store my data now

```
function Create(client) {

    // gives the client the right id
    client.fkIdUser = $localStorage.userid;

    //add the client to the database
    $http.post('/api/addclient', client).success(function(){

        //wait for the list of clients
        $http.get('/api/getlistclients').success(function(data) {

            //Replacing the clientArray with the new array
            $localStorage.clientArray = data

        })

    });

}
```

Now i'm trying to do this without storing the data into the localstorage :

```
function GetArray() {


    $http.get('/api/getlistclients').success(function(data) {

            //Replacing the clientArray with the new array
            return data

    });
```

}

But i call the data i get an error Expected an array but got 'function GetArray()'.

```
$scope.clientlist = ClientService.GetArray;
```

But if i make use of the localStorage it works fine:

```
$scope.clientlist = $localStorage.clientArray;
```

**Edit2**

So inside the controller for the view i did something like this which seems to be working fine but i can't call it from the service because the data is not loaded into the array on time i think.

```
var vm = this;

//wait for the list of clients
$http.get('/api/getlistclients').success(function(data) {

    //Replacing the clientArray with the new array
    vm.clientArray = data;
    console.log(vm.clientArray);
    // creating list for ui-select
    $scope.client = {};

    $scope.clientlist = vm.clientArray;

})
```

Comment: The obvious answer would be to save the data in DB

Comment: Ok but i also save all the data into the database. The reason i use local storage because i want the user to edit modify all the data on the front end.

Comment: So it would be better if i make a database request on each view instead of storing the data into the local storage?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov where do you get your stats from? http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: @pawel do not be so offended, for some reason I thought that it is not supported by IE9

Comment: you aren't calling `getArray()` and also the function doesn't return anything

Comment: @charlietfl when i use a service where i call  $scope.clientlist = ClientService.GetArray(); it does not provide a error but the array isnot loaded. Any idea's why this could be happening ?

Comment: `getArray()` doesn't return anything. A return inside `success` is useless.

Comment: @charlietfl how would you proceed then ?

Comment: return the `$http` promise , call function and use promise callback to assign scope variable

Comment: Ok i will need to have to look this up how this should be done. Or could you provide me with a sample how i would do it in this scenario it would sure help me a bit forward.